# How to find the PMS (Pantone) color for a given CMYK value?

Tags: colors, cmyk, pantone

Is it possible to find the nearest PMS color of any CMYK/RGB/HSL color?

I understand that PMS is an arbitrary color system (not a space) and it's not possible to do conversions using algorithms.

I have seen ([some](http://ngin.de/cmyk2pantone/index.php?c=100&m=0&y=86&k=3&hits=10), [examples](http://www.ginifab.com/feeds/pms/cmyk_to_pantone.php)) on the web, where people who developed the tools managed to do the "conversion" form CMYK to PMS.

I'm wondering if there is a lookup technique/reference that I can use.

––

**Update**

I am not sure if this would help in finding PMS color...

> To find matches, the total sum of the differences (delta, Δ) of the CMYK color components between the input CMYK color and the matched PANTONE color is calculated for the entire table of PANTONE colors. This list is then sorted by increasing delta, so that the matches with the smallest difference are on top. Note that because the delta is not weighted, you may get matches that are optically off.